# python time problem

Tags: python, django-models, time, exif

I am using the [exif.py](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exif-py/) library. After calling

```
tags=exif.process_file(...)
```

i want to retrieve the time the image was captured. so i continue with

```
t =tags['Image DateTime'] if tags.has_key('Image DateTime') else time.time()
```

now i want to store t in django's database. For that t must be in the form 2010-07-20 14:37:12 but apparently exif delivers 2010:07:20 14:37:12 however when i go

```
type(t)
```

it returns 'instance' as opposed to float which is the result of

```
type(time.time())
```

or 'str' which is the type of string. How can I parse the value EXIF gave me to stuff it into the django model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse the `str()` value, than format the time tuple to any desired form.

An example, using the 'Image DateTime' attribute returned by EXIF.

```
>>> e1['Image DateTime']
(0x0132) ASCII=2007:09:06 06:37:51 @ 176
>>> str(e1['Image DateTime'])
'2007:09:06 06:37:51'
>>> 
>>> tag = time.strptime(str(e1['Image DateTime']),"%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> tag
time.struct_time(tm_year=2007, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=6, tm_hour=6, tm_min=37, tm_sec=51,tm_wday=3, tm_yday=249, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tag)
'2007-09-06 06:37:51'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Django works best with `datetime` objects.  Strings can  be converted to `datetime`, but you should not focus on strings.  You should focus on creating a proper `datetime` object.

Choice 1.  Figure out what actual class the exif time is.  Instead of `type(t)`, do `t.__class__` to see what it really is.  Also, so `dir(t)` to see what methods it has.  It may have methods which will create a proper float value or `time.struct_time` value.

Choice 2.  Parse the time string with `datetime.datetime.strptime` to create a proper `datetime` object.  Read this: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 0):

It looks like exif.py returns an instance of IFD_Tag. The values you want may be in t.values. You can also use datetime.strptime() to parse the string you get from the exif data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that tags['Image DateTime'], if present, returns a string like "2010:07:20 14:37:12" then you can use:

```
if tags.has_key('Image DateTime'):
    t = tags['Image DateTime'].replace(':', '-' , 2)
else:
    t = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

`replace` fixes the time-string from exif:

```
>>> '2010:07:20 14:37:12'.replace(':', '-', 2)
    '2010-07-20 14:37:12'
```

If you want GMT rather than local time use

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime())
```